# Making Sense of SVG Transform Matrices Using getCTM

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix, transformation, mathml

I have been using simple `transform` `translate` on my SVG element. Now I am converting the transformations into Matrices (& pulling my hair in the process).

On `SVG` element, upon `click`, I render an element, with a simple transform translate based on the current pageX & pageY (mouse co-ordinates).

```
<svg width="1366" height="612" class="svg" viewBox="-78.48 43.82 752.30 337.05" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="elementParent">
    <g id="cry20Cyc_0.d7h" class="ele" data-action="ele" transform="translate(269.013,169.974)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="44" height="44" opacity="1" fill="#d1d1d1" stroke-width="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" class="selectRect"></rect>
      <path d="M0,22c0,12.2,9.9,22,22,22s22-9.8,22-22S34.2,0,22,0S0,9.9,0,22" fill="#482956"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Note the translate(269.013,169.974) on the `g`. When I call `getCTM()`, I get this rather bazare value:

```
  SVGMatrix { a: 1.8157544136047363, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1.8157544136047363, e: 630.9659423828125, f: 229.06468200683594 }
```

From my understanding, the values within the matrix 'a' & 'd' represent the scaling. However, I haven't applied any scaling, where is this value coming from?

And when I run `transform` on the element. The transform array returns a much more sensible value of:

```
SVGAnimatedTransformList { 
  baseVal: SVGTransformList[1], // {a:1 b:0 c:0 d:1 e:269.013 f:169.974} 
  animVal: SVGTransformList[1] }
```

Is my presumption correct that `getCTM` is perhaps incorporating the `viewbox` values into the total output of `getCTM`?

My main question is how can I convert the mouse position `pageX` `pageY` into correct matrix value for the element bearing in mind that there is `viewbox` & the element has to be scaled to size before translation.

**UPDATE**:
I have figured out that yes, the `getCTM` does incorporate the viewbox values to return the CTM. In retrospect, it makes perfect sense. Now if someone can help with the math of incorporating the mouse co-ordinates & scale into the getCTM output, that would great :)

Comment: I have a few examples online that may help. They are under the heading: "Location, Location, Location - Finding X,Y values in SVG". See svgDiscovery.com

Comment: @FrancisHemsher You have a wonderful resource. Its also daunting to look at, understandably considering the author put so much effort over the years into it. Thank you, I'll definitely be checking out the links.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is kinda late, however a similar issue caught my attention recently. I modified the returned value of the original `getCTM` and add it to the prototype like this:

```
!function(prt){
    prt._getAbsoluteCTM = function(){
        var owner = this.ownerSVGElement || this,
            height = owner.height.baseVal.value,
            width = owner.width.baseVal.value,
            viewBoxRect = owner.viewBox.baseVal,
            vHeight = viewBoxRect.height,
            vWidth = viewBoxRect.width;
        if(!vWidth || !vHeight){
            return this.getCTM();
        }
        var sH = height/vHeight,
            sW = width/vWidth,
            matrix = owner.createSVGMatrix();
        matrix.a = sW;
        matrix.d = sH
        var realCTM = this.getCTM().multiply(matrix.inverse());
        realCTM.e = realCTM.e/sW + viewBoxRect.x;
        realCTM.f = realCTM.f/sH + viewBoxRect.y;
        return realCTM;
    }
}(SVGGraphicsElement.prototype);
```

Usage is: `element._getAbsoluteCTM()` and make sure that you include the polyfill before drawing.

If a viewBox attribute is detected it will return the "absolute CTM" otherwise it will return the same value as `element.getCTM`

Here is a minimal example which you can play around with the values on inspector:
https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/1mmh7rs6/6/